# Persuading TextToSpeech to pronounce letters of the alphabet

Tags: android, speech

I'm trying to get TextToSpeech to speak alphanumeric references in the Android emulator. If I have a string such as "31NAA123", then I insert spaces between all the characters and then submit it to the speak method. It copes OK with most letters but stumbles on the 'A's, they come out as barely audible very short "ah"s, almost as short as clicks. I've tried **replaceAll("A", "AY")** which comes out as "ay, why". I've tried most speech rates down to 0.3f - nothing works. I'm using a UK locale to give a British accent. I'd be grateful if anyone has any useful suggestions.

(I suspect 'i' will give similar problems, 'o' seems to be OK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried inserting multiple points after the letters? Seems to work pretty well for me:

```
String s = "a.. b.. c..";
```

Or even slower:

```
String s = "a... b... c...";
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I already had the space between letters, so a call to replaceAll(" ", ".. ") fixed it. I like one line fixes!